# Laravel and spatie/laravel-permission - plucking names of roles to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-permission, pluck

I want in Laravel to "pluck" to the view names of roles, each in different badge.

My code:

```
<td><span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $user->roles()->pluck('name')->implode(' ') }}</span></td>
```

My result:

[image]

I am getting all role names in one span class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

```
<td>
    @foreach($user->roles()->pluck('name') as $role_name){
       <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $role_name }}</span>
    @endforeach
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    @foreach($user->roles as $role){
        <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $role->name }}</span>
    @endforeach
</td>
```

I think this is what you want.